10.3.2. Singularity用のイメージに変換
Docker用のイメージからSingularity用のイメージへの変換を実施しています
しかしながら、エラーでできません。助言をいただければ幸いです
docker:$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
            -v $PWD/out_singularity:/output \
            --privileged -t --rm \
            quay.io/singularity/docker2singularity \
            --name my_singularity_image-0.1 \
            user_name/my_image:0.1

Image Format: squashfs
Docker Image: user_name/my_image:0.1
Container Name: my_singularity_image-0.1

Inspected Size: 64 MB

(1/10) Creating a build sandbox...
(2/10) Exporting filesystem...
(3/10) Creating labels...
Error relocating /usr/local/singularity/bin/singularity: seccomp_notify_respond: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/singularity/bin/singularity: seccomp_notify_alloc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/singularity/bin/singularity: seccomp_notify_free: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/singularity/bin/singularity: seccomp_notify_receive: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/singularity/bin/singularity: seccomp_notify_fd: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/singularity/bin/singularity: seccomp_notify_id_valid: symbol not found


タイトルで検索すると参照しているのはこの辺りの記事でしょうか？ https://sc.megabank.tohoku.ac.jp/ph3-doc/howto/linux/singularity.html#id9
